# Accessing info about rubygem from within ruby script

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I need to get the installation path for a given ruby gem and can't find any information on how to do that. Given:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
require 'rubygems'
require 'somegem'
```

How can I find out where the installation path of `somegem` is on the system (without resorting to `system(gem ...)`. The gem in question comes with some icons which I want to reference in my script.

Thanks to Chris I now have the following assembled:

```
require 'rubygems/Commands/contents_command'
c = Gem::Commands::ContentsCommand.new
c.options[:args] = 'somegem'
c.execute
```

However, `c.execute` immediately outputs the result on stdout. How can I catch that in a variable for further processing? `res = c.execute` does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have different ways to achieve this:

```
Gem.source_index.find_name('somegem').last.full_gem_path
```

You could also just grep your load path:

```
$:.grep /somegem/
```

Comment: Thanks, the Gem.source_index method is exactly what I needed.